# Deleting Associated table Data from HABTM relation in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many

My relationship is like

```
             Post<HABTM>Tag
```

When I add a new post and corresponding tags it is saving in posts table and tags table and save the ids of both in posts_tags table. Everything is working fine with cakephp HABTM,
but now I want to delete a post.
I wrote the code:

```
           $this->Post->delete($id);
```

this deleted the corresponding post with given id and delete the association in the posts_tags table that also working fine.
I want to delete the post and corresponding tags in the tags table and values in the mapping table posts_tags.
How we can do this in a single shot? Is there any way?
Otherwise tell me any solution..I am confused

Comment: Accoriding to this http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/deleting-data.html you should be able to delete related data by calling it just like that. Please provide your model code and database structure.

Comment: What you are asking is not realistic. If you delete a Tag with Post then the other posts depends on that Tag will mother less.....

Comment: @Fazal Rasel ya you r right. the real problem is i have a user table,employee table and address table, each user and employee have 1 or more address. so now i  have made user HABTM address and employeee HABTM address. so when i delete the user, it is deleting the record of addresses_users table and users table but not in the address table . that is my problem. is there any way..? please help me